# how to add Apache Tomcat6 to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

when i go to windows preferences, there is no Tomcat6 !!!

how can i add tomcat6 new server runtime environment  in eclipse 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add a new one via:
1. Go to Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments
2. Click on the Add... button
3. Expand the Apache directory to get the list of all Apache servers
4. Select Apache Tomcat v6.0
5. Fill in installation details


If you're not seeing this you might need to check you have the Java EE version of Eclipse and that your installation is up to date.

Comment: yup, figured it out! but it involved downloading the Sysdeo tomcat6 launcher....it was quite weird set up before when I was using Java SE.